# Table Border CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table in HTML and expecting that all the border in the table is in same weight, but I get this result where there is some rows that have different border weight

[image]

The HTML code is in this structure (full HTML can't be posted as it is considered too much code by StackOverflow)

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: rgb(20, 35, 58);
  word-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

thead{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Vehicle Name</td>
            <td>Tour</td>
            <td>Total Distance</td>
            <td>Total Charge</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Vehicle 1</td>
            <td>1 2 3</td>
            <td>101.2</td>
            <td>1012</td>
        </tr>
        ....
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: can you share the corresponding HTML?

Comment: okay i updated my answear with you html. take a look maybe it helps

Comment: Just a addition about _"full HTML can't be posted as it is considered too much code by StackOverflow"_: Thats correct. Youre never supposed to share your "full code" but only the relevant code for the problem (see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Adding as few code as possible for the problem to show up makes solving the problem much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 4 columns then you can add `width: 25%` to the td style.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  color: rgb(20, 35, 58);
  word-spacing: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 25%;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

thead{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
 <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Vehicle Name</td>
        <td>Tour</td>
        <td>Total Distance</td>
        <td>Total Charge</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Vehicle 1</td>
        <td>1 2 3</td>
        <td>101.2</td>
        <td>1012</td>
    </tr>
    ....
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: have tried but still the same, except the column width is identical

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to recreate the issue under normal condition, but when I changed the dimension of my web browser, the browsers attempt to rescale the table created the OP's described issue. I solved this issue by changing  `border: 1px`
to  `border: 0.01vw`. This tells the browser explicitly how to scale the table and therefore avoids the problem.

---

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 0.01vw solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: rgb(20, 35, 58);
    word-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  
  td {
    border: 0.01vw solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  tr {
    height: 20px;
  }
  
  thead{
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle Name</td>
                <td>Tour</td>
                <td>Total Distance</td>
                <td>Total Charge</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle 1</td>
                <td>1 2 3</td>
                <td>101.2</td>
                <td>1012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle 2</td>
                <td>1 2 3</td>
                <td>101.2</td>
                <td>1012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle 3</td>
                <td>1 2 3</td>
                <td>101.2</td>
                <td>1012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle 4</td>
                <td>1 2 3</td>
                <td>101.2</td>
                <td>1012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle 5</td>
                <td>1 2 3</td>
                <td>101.2</td>
                <td>1012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle 6</td>
                <td>1 2 3</td>
                <td>101.2</td>
                <td>1012</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vehicle 7</td>
                <td>1 2 3</td>
                <td>101.2</td>
                <td>1012</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: it solves the problem, thank you :D